# Can I transfer SQL Query into a FUNCTION?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function

Currently, I have some SQL queries which looks like this:

```
Drop Table X;

Create Table X(id INTEGER);

Insert Into X
select ..
from..
where a.name = GIVENNAME;

Select SUM(..)
from ..
..
order by date desc;
```

And I want to put all these into a SQL Function, where I can choose the Parameter "GIVENNAME" when I call the function.

Is there a way to make this possible?

I would know how to do it in JSON/Java, but I have really no clue how to make it as a Function in SQL (using Oracle).

---

Edit:
After pointing out some things, I want to add my current code:

```
DROP TABLE TEMPTABLE;

CREATE TABLE TEMPTABLE
(mitID INTEGER);


INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE
select m.mitid
from mitarbeiter m
inner join abteilungen a on m.abt = a.abtid
where a.abtname = @GIVENNAME;


select SUM(g.kosten)
from gehaelter g
left outer join gehaelter k
on g.mitarbeiter = k.mitarbeiter 
and g.vondatum < k.vondatum
where k.mitarbeiter is null AND g.mitarbeiter in (select * from TEMPTABLE) 
order by g.vondatum desc;
```

Comment: The obvious question is why do you have those DROP, CREATE, INSERT statements? That's going to perform horribly and will be highly unsafe in a production environment. What's wrong with `select sum(whatever) from your_table where name = GIVENNAME`?

Comment: @APC because first I need to crate a table with specific entries, otherwise i wont get the expected result.

I don't mind about the safety etc.. tbh, just need to transfer the queries into a function, somehow.

Comment: @APC Since it is not the most complex code, it is indeed possible to get the same result with a single select statement. But I'm currently more interested in a working solution than a nice & clean one - but I added the whole code now.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are completely different products.  Use the tag properly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm currently more interested in a working solution than a nice & clean one

Fortunately you can have both:

```
create or replace function get_sum_kosten
   ( p_givenname in abteilungen.abtname%type )
   return number
as
    return_value number;
begin
    select SUM(g.kosten)
    into return_value
    from gehaelter g
    left outer join gehaelter k
    on g.mitarbeiter = k.mitarbeiter 
    and g.vondatum < k.vondatum
    where k.mitarbeiter is null 
    AND g.mitarbeiter in (select m.mitid
                           from mitarbeiter m
                           inner join abteilungen a on m.abt = a.abtid
                           where a.abtname = P_GIVENNAME
        ) 
    ;
    return return_value;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you!
I will try to improve myself the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Possible? Yes. Recommended? No.

For any DDL, you'd have to use dynamic SQL (`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`). If queries are complex, those commands will be difficult to maintain.

`INSERT` is a DML, but you can't use it in a **function**, unless it is an autonomous transaction (and you'll have to commit (or rollback) within the function).

If it were a **procedure**, you'd - at least - avoid the last problem I mentioned. If you're returning *something*, use an `OUT` parameter.

Can't you use a (global) temporary table, instead? Create it once, use it many times. I understand that your code might be very complex and maybe it really can't fit into a single `SELECT` statement, but you should - at least - try to do that job in an Oracle spirit (i.e. it is not MS SQL Server).

Answer (score 0):

example of **procedure**
https://www.sitepoint.com/stored-procedures-mysql-php/
like this

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `avg_sal`(out avg_sal decimal)
BEGIN
    select avg(sal) into avg_sal from salary;

END
```

Comment: Sorry but there really isn't much value in supplying toy code which doesn't actually use the data model and business logic posted in the question.

Comment: Sorry but I give example of that

Comment: It's good that you want to be helpful, but being helpful means writing answers that are focused on the OP's actual problem. Please compare your sample code with the question and the code I provided in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55345066/146325). Writing a good answer on StackOverflow requires more effort than cut'n'pasting some random stuff  from a Google search. For starters, the OP asks for a function and your code is a procedure.